# When we have a universal approximator, can we approximate any nonnegative function by passing the approximator to ReLU activation?

Tags: approximation, positive-semidefinite

Consider the domain of all functions that will be mentioned is $X$, a compact subspace of $\mathbb{R}^n$.

Suppose that, given a continuous function $f$, $\forall \epsilon > 0$, $\exists \hat{f} \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $\lVert f - \hat{f} \rVert_{\infty} < \epsilon$.

Then, for any nonnegative continuous function $g$, for every $\epsilon > 0$, does there exist $\hat{f} \in \mathcal{F}$ such that $\lVert g - \max(0, \hat{f})\rVert_{\infty} < \epsilon$?

That is, when we have a universal approximator $\mathcal{F}$ for continuous functions, can we approximate any nonnegative function by the form of $\max(0, \hat{f})$ where $\hat{f} \in \mathcal{F}$?

Comment: Just note that $|y - \max(0,z)|\leq |y-z|$ if $y \geq 0$. Why does this hold? Why does it help you?

Comment: I was an idiot. Thank you for your help :)

EDIT: for other readers, from @PhoemueX 's answer,
1) if $z \geq 0$: $|y - \max(0, z)| = |y - z|$
2) if $z < 0$: $|y - \max(0, z)| = |y| \leq |y - z|$

Comment: You can also answer you own question, then the question won't remain marked as unanswered (I am too lazy to type up an answer :D).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please see the comments; I don't know whether it is possible to change this question as answered without an answer, so I posted this answer.